# Auto segue when rootViewControl loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, rootview

I have a Navigation Controller in a storyboard set as the initial view. It calls one `viewController`, lets call it `inititalViewCon`. I want `initialViewCon` to modally segue to another `viewController` *as soon as* it loads.

So it would open the app, go to `initialViewCon` and then have a modal segue pop up. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you reviewed the UIViewController documentation? - In particular you should look at `viewDidAppear`.  If your modal view controller is in your storyboard you should also investigate `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: So I have to do it programmatically? By subclassing the ViewController?

Comment: Yes, you have to do this in code, which means you do have to subclass the view controller.

Comment: You always have to subclass `UIViewController` as this is where you have the code to process the interaction between the user and your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subclassed the `UIViewController`, the second one, which I know is against Apple's guidelines.

I added this method to the subclass:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It's kind of strange that you can initiate a modal segue from a storyboard but there's no way to dismiss it without subclassing the `viewController`.

Comment: Why would you say that subclassing `UIViewController` is against Apple guidelines?

Comment: And you can do it in storyboards by using an unwind segue

Comment: @Paulw11 not subclassing the UIViewController, but giving control the second view controller to dismiss itself. Apple says to keep control with the first view controller

Comment: Again, nothing wrong with that. Particularly in the case of a modal view controller - the view controller that is being presented will often know best when it's work is done. You could separate control out of all UIViewControllers into a controller class in a more pure MVC style, but you would still have to subclass the UIViewControllers with the subclass using a delegate pattern or completion block to notify the controller class that it should (or should potentially) be dismissed